# How to override Jtoolbarhelper::deletelist method?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, custom-component

I have created a custom component which is used to implement custom ecommerce functionality. Admin can see and manage all orders from backend. What is want is whenever admin delete/cancel any order mail is sent to that the customer email id.
I want to know how can i override or add my code to mail to the deletelist method so that it mail sent when admin deletes order's record only.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation says, the `JToolbarHelper::deleteList`

```php
/**
 * JToolbarHelper/deleteList
 * Writes a common 'delete' button for a list of records.
 *
 * @param   string  $msg   Postscript for the 'are you sure' message.
 * @param   string  $task  An override for the task.
 * @param   string  $alt   An override for the alt text.
 *
 * @return  void
 *
 * @since   1.5
 */
```

Therefore, you have several options:

1. Override the controller's `remove` task by either overriding the `remove` method:

   ```php
   class MycomponentControllerMycontroller extends JControllerAdmin{

       public function remove() {
           //stuff goes here
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register the `remove` task in the cont

   ```php
   class MycomponentControllerMycontroller extends JControllerAdmin{
       public function __construct($config = array())
       {
           parent::__construct($config);
           //...
           $this->registerTask('remove', 'myMethod');

       }

       public function myMethod() {
           //stuff goes here
       }
   }
   ```
3. provide the `$task` argument to override the `remove` task.

   toolbar button creation:

   ```php
   JToolbarHelper::deleteList('', 'mycontroller.myMethod', 'JTOOLBAR_EMPTY_TRASH');
   ```

   and the controller:

   ```php
   class MycomponentControllerMycontroller extends JControllerAdmin{

       public function myMethod() {
           //stuff goes here
       }
   }
   ```

The controller in this example should be located in in `administrator/components/mycomponent/controllers/mycontroller`.